# Is there a better solution than adding || [ ] to each field for a null check in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, null, undefined

I am working with a child `component` where an `array` item is passed as prop. However, that item also contains another `array` where there should be `null` and `undefined` check before rendering. Adding `|| []` to each filed didn't seem the best way. Is there a better way that I am missing?

```
const ChildComponent= ({ newsItem, textColor, newsItemHeadingColor }) => {
  const imageFormats = newsItem?.itemImage?.formats;
  const imageSrc = useProgressiveImage({ formats: imageFormats });
  const history = useHistory();

  const { state } = useContextState();
  const { schemeMode, colorSchemes } = state;

  const { itemTagColor, itemTagTextColor } = getThemeColors({
    schemeMode,
    colorSchemes,
    colors: {
      itemTagColor: newsItem?.itemTagColor?.name,
      itemTagTextColor: newsItem?.itemTagTextColor?.name,
    },
  });

  return (
    <NewsItem
      onClick={() => {
        const url =
          newsItem?.itemTag === 'Lab'
            ? getPageLink({
                page: newsItem?.itemLink || [], <<<<<< this check
              })
            : newsItem?.itemLink || []; <<<<<< this check
        url && history.push(url);
      }}
    >
      <ImageContainer>
        <Image src={imageSrc} alt={`${newsItem?.itemImage || []}`} /> <<<<<< this check
      </ImageContainer>
      <NewsItemTag color={itemTagColor} itemTagTextColor={itemTagTextColor}>
        <Body4>{`${newsItem?.itemTag || []}`}</Body4>               <<<<<< this check
      </NewsItemTag>
      <NewsItemName newsItemHeadingColor={newsItemHeadingColor}>{`${
        newsItem?.itemTitle || []                                     <<<<<< this check
      }`}</NewsItemName>
      <Description textColor={textColor}>{`${
        (newsItem.description &&
          newsItem?.itemDescription) || []                          <<<<<< this check
      }`}</Description>
    </NewsItem>
  );
};
```

Comment: It is not clear why you want an array, without us knowing what `itemLink`, `itemTag`, `itemImage` have as possible values. What's more, a question should just focus on the issue, and I think you can present that with three lines of code instead of 40.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but in terms of providing default values, use `??` (nullish coalescing) instead of `||`. Nullish coalescing returns first non-null, defined value instead of truthy value.

Comment: data type for `itemLink`, `itemTag` is `string` and `itemImage` is `image`. These are the values picked from the `db`. Values are rendered in various `div`, which are created using `styled-component`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact yes, you have many many ways for improving your code and the readabilty of it.

In your `<NewItem />` `onClick` function:

- I have nothing to say for the first one, it seems correct since you want the item link or an empty array
- For the second one, your are already using the `optional chaining operator`, the "?". This operator check if there is a value, if not, it returns `null`. That means that should be enough, since you check after your `url` variable is defined or not. So simply write that : `: newsItem?.itemLink`

For the third one, the one on your `<Image />` component, First there is no need at all to put everything in backquote. Simply `alt={newsItem?.itemImage || []}` should work fine. Then, `alt attribute` is taking a string, so maybe change it with `alt={newsItem?.itemImage || ""}`

For the three last one, they are basically the same, you have content to display and you want to display nothing if there are empty. The fact here is that your are rendering some elements even if there is no content and this is not an optimized way. The cleanest way in my opinion in order to make your template more readable will be to define variable before your `return function` and based on this variable, you will display the appropriate section :

**Before your return function:**

```
const hasTag = !!newsItem?.itemTag;
const hasTitle = !!newsItem?.itemTitle;
const hasDescription = !!newsItem.description && !!newsItem?.itemDescription;
```

**In your template:**

```js
    {hasTag && <NewsItemTag color={itemTagColor} itemTagTextColor={itemTagTextColor}>
      <Body4>{newsItem.itemTag}</Body4>
</NewsItemTag>}
{hasTitle && <NewsItemName newsItemHeadingColor={newsItemHeadingColor}>
      {newsItem.itemTitle}
</NewsItemName>
{hasDescription && <Description textColor={textColor}>
      {newsItem.itemDescription}
</Description>
```

I hope this was clear, hit me up if this wasn't.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you could handle this in javascript, assume that we have a component that receives a prop called `newsItem` which is an object

### You could do that in the following ways

- Using the logical operator or (es6)

```
 const itemLinks = newsItem.links || []
```

you dont need the optional chaining operator `(?.)` here if you know that newsItem is an `object` and not `undefined`.

This is the shortest syntax, and it works fine as long as `links` is either `undefined` or an `array`
however it becomes problematic if later `links` become a `boolean` variable, which will yield incorrect results
This method is not safe, and it becomes cumbersome to handle as properties become nested deeply

- Using lodash [get method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) or some other library or a custom solution (es6)

because in es6 the only practical way was to either the logical operator and this was a common problem, custom solutions were brought it, basically any solution should have two advantages over the logical or operator

1. They should work fine with boolean values
2. They should be easier to work with deeply nested values

```
custom someDeepleyNested = get(newsItem, 'property1.property2.property3', 'defaultValue')
// there is no need for property1, property2, property3 to exist at all
```

- [Optional chaining operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) and [Nullish coalescing Operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) (stage 4 finished proposals)

Because this was a common problem for all javascript developers,the language had to bring a native solution

```
const someNestedProperty = newsItem?.property1?.property2?.property3 ?? 'someDefaultValue'

// notice that both the Optional chaining operator and Nullish coalescing Operator, work with both undefined and null
```

- Specific to react: use default props

```
const Component = ({newsLink}) => {}
Component.defaultProps = {
 newsItem: {
    itemLinks: []
 }
}
```